# Python email sending, header seems empty, rejected as SPAM

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

I am trying to send an email with a zip attachment using a very simple python script from answers found in previous posts.

My script look like this:

```
import smtplib
from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

to_addres = "*******"
from_addr = "*******"
mail_server = "*******"
zf = open("/home/******/asd.zip", "rb")


text = '''
Hello,

Here is your test email.

Cheers!
'''
msg = MIMEMultipart(text)
msg.add_header('From', from_addr)
msg.add_header("To", to_addres)
msg.add_header("Subject", "Test")

attachemnt = MIMEBase('application', 'zip')
attachemnt.set_payload(zf.read())
encoders.encode_base64(attachemnt)
attachemnt.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename="asd.zip")
msg.attach(attachemnt)

server = smtplib.SMTP(mail_server, 25)
server.ehlo()
server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addres, msg.as_string())
server.close()
```

Everything seems okey, however when i send the email from my provider to a testing GMAIL account i get blocked as SPAM.

Part of the error message i get back:

```
 -0.6 RP_MATCHES_RCVD        Envelope sender domain matches handover relay domain
  2.1 MISSING_HEADERS        Missing To: header
 -0.1 BAYES_00               BODY: Bayes spam probability is 0 to 1%
                             [score: 0.0000]
  0.0 TVD_SPACE_RATIO        No description available.
  1.0 MISSING_DATE           Missing Date: header
  1.0 MISSING_MID            Missing Message-Id: header
  1.8 MISSING_SUBJECT        Missing Subject: header
  1.0 MISSING_FROM           Missing From: header
  0.7 MIME_HEADER_CTYPE_ONLY 'Content-Type' found without required MIME
                             headers
X-ACL-Warn: condition = yes
```

So it seems the email header is empty? How so? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that `filename="asd.zip"` is correct? You haven't provided the path to it?

Comment: @MilanVelebit It is correct, the absolute path at `zf` points to it. It is just a 1KB test ZIP file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is responsible for the problem:

```
msg = MIMEMultipart(text)
```

It adds the `text` (which is a multiline string) to the `Content-Type` Header. This creates an invalid message format.

Do this instead:

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg.attach(MIMEText(text, 'plain'))
```

where `MIMEText` must be imported from `email.mime.text`

Comment: Thanks a lot, solved the problem. Only banged my head for 2 hours because of this...